# Black screen after splash and partition file system unknown

Tags: boot, 13.10, gui, boot-repair, partitioning

**Problem** Since yesterday. when I boot the computer, after the splash logo, the screen turns black. I can go to a tty screen, but anything that I try to open graphically fails. (I am not the most experienced terminal user.)

**Last actions before the problem**
The only thing I can remember doing before this problem started is, installing extra TeX-live packages and updating the computer. I don't remember what it was that needed updating.

**What I have done so far**
(1) Gparted tells me one of my small partitions (~4 GB has a unknown file system). I haven't created such a small partition, and I am not sure from which other partition this has been 'taken'. I checked this  post [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and I looked at the answer about "if this occurred after an update", I will have a look at the boot partitioning issues. to see if I can find out more.

UPDATE: The 4GB partition apparently was my swap partition. I reformatted it to swap, the problem did not get fixed and this partition is back to being of a file system "unknown".

(2) Recovery mode doesn't 'open', i.e. on different options, partitions are checked and then nothing.

(3) Boot-repair didn't fix the problem (http://paste.ubuntu.com/6878058), but I reckon the boot is indeed not the problem.

(4) Other similar problems I found on forums were either with 12.04 upgrade to 12.10 (I have 13.10 64 bit), or it seems to have to do with their graphics cards. However I did not change anything about the graphics as far as I can remember for months.

**My system** I have Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, single boot with several partitions, AMD64 Athlon II X3, 3.2 GHz, 4GB RAM, ATI Radeon HD4250.

**What now?** I will now keep on finding new things to try, but some of them are bit too complicated for me. If anyone can help me, you're help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu (I have the OS on a separate partition) and that solved the problem. However, still no idea how this occurred and how it could have been solved.